# Trying to translate absolute URL from an SVN to its local file path on your IDE

Tags: java, svn, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to determine the exact absolute path of the local file from only having available the absolute path from the SVN. The whole idea is that I'm writing an eclipse plugin that from knowing the URL to a file in the SVN you could click a row and the corresponding file locally from within eclipse would be opened.

Where I’m running into difficulty is trying to determine exactly where the SVN path ends and the actual file begins locally. Let me give an actual example to demonstrate.

Let’s say the absolute URL to the file in the SVN is:

http://webappsecure.com/svn/discovery/sentinel2jirav4/src/main/java/com/whitehatsecurity/jira/configurations/IPluginConfigurationSettings.java

That same file can be found in eclipse at this location on the users computer:

C:\Users\Steve\workspace\Jira Plugins\Sentinel2Jirav4\sentinel2jirav4\src\main\java\com\whitehatsecurity\jira\configurations\IPluginConfigurationSettings.java

There are some differences for sure in the structures of the paths.

You see how in the SVN  the URL is:

/svn/discovery/sentinel2jirav4/

The local path from eclipse is:

\Jira Plugins\Sentinel2Jirav4\sentinel2jirav4\

It looks like I may be able to have a preference page where I have the user add the path to the svn so like: /svn/discovery/

Therefore every absolute URL I get from the SVN would then be chopped off all the way to /svn/discovery.

Is there a better way to correlate the SVN path to its path locally? Does the SVN store that local path info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should read about local structure of svn (`.svn` folder and `entries` file inside .svn folder), that obtained in result of `checkout`
Second, you need to parse .svn/entries for all folders inside you %WORKSPACE%.
After that you would exactly know relation between local folder and url in the SVN

For instance: `src/main/java/com/whitehatsecurity/jira/configurations/IPluginConfigurationSettings.java`
inside root folder `src` should be folder named `.svn`, in which should be located file `entries`. Inside of file `.svn/entries` should be following lines:

```
dir
3
http://webappsecure.com/svn/discovery/sentinel2jirav4/src
http://webappsecure.com/svn
```

Or you can just run `svn info C:\Users\Steve\workspace\Jira Plugins\Sentinel2Jirav4\sentinel2jirav4\src` for each folder, which contains `.svn` inside.
And as a result get something like

```
Path: workspace\Jira Plugins\Sentinel2Jirav4\sentinel2jirav4\src
URL: http://webappsecure.com/svn/discovery/sentinel2jirav4/src
Repository Root: http://webappsecure.com/src
etc...
```

Comment: This looks like a good start but when i look in .svn for the project the entries file just has a number 12. Not what your showing in your example?